# Is there a way to create a handler for the RoundRectangle (sealed) control?

Tags: maui, handler

I'm working to migrate a Xamarin forms app to MAUI, as you probably know if you are reading this, MAUI has quite the list of bugs still pending to be solved. I'm using handlers as a way to workaround them, but I'm currently stuck at trying to workaround this bug:
https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/14936

I was trying to create a handler for [RoundRectangle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.shapes.roundrectangle?view=net-maui-7.0) on Android, to modify the `CornerRadius` property, but found that the class is sealed.

Is there a way to get around that without having to create my own control implementing all of the methods and properties?

And I know, this is going to be fixed in a better and definite way on the next patch release, however i would still like to learn from knowledgeable folks in this group if this is feasible, for when I encounter a similar scenario.

I have also tried to create a handler for the Border control instead, but I couldn't find a way to modify its RoundRectangle child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There basically need to be a Handler if you want to make changes to a control.  Otherwise you need to override in other ways, like on every platform and use it's specific way to do things, and tie it together with your own handler.

Regarding `RoundRectangle` there are a handler for you to use.

```cs
public partial class RoundRectangleHandlerEx : RoundRectangleHandler
{
    public static new IPropertyMapper<RoundRectangle, RoundRectangleHandler> Mapper = new PropertyMapper<RoundRectangle, RoundRectangleHandler>(RoundRectangleHandler.Mapper)
    {
        [nameof(RoundRectangle.CornerRadius)] = MapCornerRadius
    };

    public RoundRectangleHandlerEx() : base(Mapper)
    {

    }

    public RoundRectangleHandlerEx(IPropertyMapper mapper) : base(mapper ?? Mapper)
    {

    }

    public new static void MapCornerRadius(IShapeViewHandler handler, RoundRectangle roundRectangle)
    {
        handler.PlatformView?.InvalidateShape(roundRectangle);
    }
}
```